# Can a static electric charge stably levitate using the superposition of electric potentials?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

According to Earnshaw's theorem for electrostatic fields a charge cannot be kept in stable equilibrium by purely electrostatic fields. The mathematical proof for this is usually as follows:
if the electric field $\vec{E}$ has a scalar potential $\phi(x,y,z)$, with $\vec{E}=-\nabla\phi$, then $\vec{E}$ follows Laplace's equation where no charges are present, so
$$\nabla^{2}\phi=0.$$
$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=0,$$
Now if, for example, $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}<0$ and $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}<0$, with $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}>0$ such that the addition of all three will still sum up to $0$, then it seems to me the electrostatic field can still be stable, however, only in maximally two directions.
Image if we superpose two electric potentials, say, $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ that each individually satisfy Laplace's equation. Where $\phi_{1}$ is radially stable, meaning $\frac{\partial^2\phi_{1}}{\partial x^2}<0$, $\frac{\partial^2\phi_{1}}{\partial y^2}<0$ and $\frac{\partial^2\phi_{1}}{\partial z^2}>0$. Moreover, $\phi_{2}$ is only axially stable, implying $\frac{\partial^2\phi_{2}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi_{2}}{\partial y^2}>0$ and $\frac{\partial^2\phi_{2}}{\partial z^2}<0$. Now if we were to combine $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ we would acquire an electrostatic field that is both radially and axially stable, and still complies with Laplace's equation. The only caveat is that this method would require two separate electrostatic fields. 
As a result, my question is, can we use this above technique to stably levitate a charged body, by combining two electrostatic fields that individually aren't fully stably, but their superposition is.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are "two separate electrostatic fields"?

Comment: @FlatterMann By two separate electrostatic fields I meant two fields generated by two separate charge distributions. Combining the two would create 'one' resultant field.

Comment: Yes, that is one field and Earnshaw's theorem proves that one field can not have a stable equilibrium point. There is no second field.

Comment: But I've just shown that if you combine two partially stable fields you can make the resultant field stable.

Comment: I don't think you can suppose the fields you've supposed, they have additional requirements such as having zero gurl and divergence, but I cannot imagine a field that would also have the properties you've given it.

Comment: Do you understand that the Laplace equation still applies to the total potential that is the result of adding the two different potentials? So $\nabla^2\phi_1=0$, $\nabla^2\phi_2=0$, $\phi_T=\phi_1+\phi_2$, then unfortunately $\nabla^2\phi_T=0$. So $\phi_T$ cannot be a stable trap for the same reason $\phi_1$ alone cannot be a stable trap

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to (over)simplify your scenario:

- Take three numbers that add to 0: (-3, -8, 11)
- Take other three
  numbers that add to 0: (1, 2, -3)
- Add them up component-wise: (-2, -6, 8)

No matter what three numbers you choose, if they add up to 0, their superposition will always sum 0, and so at least one number will be non-negative :)

Answer (score 0):

Your total force depends on $\phi=\phi_1+\phi_2$ which satisfy Laplace equation, so it inevitably has one normal mode that is unstable.

Your $\phi_1$ might be radially stable. Your second field might be axially stable. However, when you sum up the two fields, the radial component of the second field might mess up the radial stability of the sum despite the first field is radially stable. The axial component of the first might mess up the axial stability of the sum despite the axial stability of the second field. One of the mess-up must occur because of the proof from Laplace equation.

This is how proof in math works. It just must be true. Other things like the possible mess-up must occur because the consequence of the proof must be true.